# MacBook Air (2015) Trackpad and keyboard not working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

My MacBook Air's internal keyboard and Trackpad have stopped working. To be honest, she had a bit of a fall about 2 weeks ago, about 3 feet onto carpet, it has worked fine ever since yesterday. I reset PRAM and SMC, no luck.

Works totally fine with external mouse and keyboard. How do I get it working again?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the internal connectors for keyboard and Trackpad have lost contact from the main logic board. It is advisable to get it inspected by an authorised Apple technician.

Comment: Amy idea of how much that will cost? The laptop is still under apple care.

Comment: No idea. Only an Apple Store/authorized service provider can answer that. If you have an active Apple Care protection plan, any services and spares may be covered for free (as per Apple Care policy).

Comment: Thank you for your help! In your opinion, is this a major fix? I am a struggling student and am just worried about the cost...

Comment: As I said no comment can be made without inspection. Your best resort would be to visit an Apple Store/Authorized service provider and they will be able to answer any/all questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ribbon cable, and it cost about 8 bucks on Amazon.